# Why the dynamic nonlinear differential equations of plate are said to be of eight order?

Tags: classical-mechanics, differential-equations

In Chia Chuen-yuan's book *Nolinear Analysis of Plates*, on the begining of section 1.8, the author said that "any system of nonlinear differential equations is of eight order". I can only figure out four order, where is the other four order is? Below is a photo of this sentence.
[image]

An example of system of equations is shown below
[image]

In J.N. Reddy's book *Mechanics of Laminated Composite Plates and Shells, Theory and Analysis*, an identical statement can also be found.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Can you convert the picture of the text into typed-out, formatted text? It makes the content index-able by search engines, and shows up better on different devices' displays. For formulae, try [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: These pictures are just for reference. A glance at the red underline and frame is enough. If the order of this website must be kept and maintained, I would delete them.

Comment: There is missing context however, what is the comma for in the subscripts where the derivative subscripts sit.

Comment: The book said "a comma denotes partial differentiation with respect to the corresponding coordinates." This is the common usage of the comma in the subscripts in books and journal articles.

Answer (score 2):

The author mentions that the order of the system is 8 because it is formed by two fourth-order differential equations that are coupled.

If you were considering plates, the simplest theory is of order 4. But, because of the curvature of shells, you have bending coupled with tangential deformations (membrane effects).